# xpath contains(text(),'some string' doesn't work when used with element of an array

Tags: java

I want to use an element of an array for xpath contains text() but it doesn' work

My code is

```
public void checkRandomHobbies() throws InterruptedException{
        String[] hobbies = {"Sports", "Reading", "Music"};
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//label[contains(text(), '" + OptimizeTest_StringUnits.randomItems(hobbies) + "']")).click();
    }
```

but when I used the following xpath and it worked:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//label[contains(text(),'Sports')]")).click();
```

Here is my code for random item

```
static String randomItems(String[] strArray){
    String rItem = strArray[generate.nextInt(strArray.length)];
    return rItem;
}
```

so how can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe use String.format() for formatting your string since we can't figure out what went wrong with your implementation.